What are the key differences, with respect to meta-ethics and philosophical method, between P. F. Strawson and Alasdair Macintyre?
There seem to be some similarities. Macintyre argues that the virtues are internal to social practices and traditions while Strawson argues for a method of 'descriptive metaphysics' whereby philosophers analyse how ethical concepts function in ordinary language and practices. They both reject grand abstractions in favour of a historically and culturally situated approach to ethics. I am wondering whether they are just using different language to describe very similar approaches or if there are deeper meta-ethical and methodological disagreements between them?

If you start from the fact that MacIntyre is fairly Christian whereas Strawson is much more ambiguous on his stand the result should follow (I think!)

This is a good question and it would be nice for an expert in metaethics to give a substantial answer. I can offer a couple of hints.
Strawson is concerned with describing under what conditions people make moral judgments, what they mean by them, and what role they play in human interactions and practices. It is a descriptive project in the tradition of ordinary language philosophy. He is not concerned with trying to set out a theory of what is good or bad, right or wrong, virtuous or vicious.
MacIntyre is rather more ambitious in this respect. He advocates for an Aristotelian and Thomistic understanding of moral virtues and he holds that Enlightenment and modern approaches to metaethics have gone astray by losing the classical focus on virtues. So, to some extent at least, MacIntyre is not just trying to describe the moral landscape but to diagnose what he sees as a flaw in it. According to MacIntyre, modern moral thinking is in a state of malaise that is the consequence of our inheriting numerous conflicting moral paradigms.

Macintyre thinks our moral concepts are constructed within social traditions, so facts about whether X is a courageous act are determined by what counts as a courageous act within the language of the moral community. These 'practice-internal' moral concepts are not tracking extralinguistic moral reality. So far, Strawson agrees. However, Macintyre also wants a way to normatively adjudicate between communities as to how well they promote human flourishing. At this stage, he 'goes metaphysical' in a way Strawson would reject. Perhaps Macintyre's project is thus less methodologically coherent?
